# Is there something wrong with CommonMark?

Tags: commonmark

If you try **b.**a on https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/, you would see its **b.** is not bolded.
However, if you just omit the last a, it works.

What is the CommonMark format to bold it correctly (that is bolded **a.**, followed by unbolded `b`)?

The solution to format the text correctly in CommonMark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [section 6.2 of the CommonMark specification](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#emphasis-and-strong-emphasis), that behaviour is by design:

> A delimiter run is either a sequence of one or more * characters [...]
>
> A right-flanking delimiter run is a delimiter run that is (1) not preceded by Unicode whitespace, and either (2a) **not preceded by a Unicode punctuation character**, or (2b) preceded by a Unicode punctuation character and followed by Unicode whitespace or a Unicode punctuation character.

You can get the desired visual appearance with `**b.**&#8203;a`, where `&#8203;` is the HTML entity "zero-width joiner", thus:

**b.**​a

...and we've just found a [bug in the rendering here on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422992/markdown-rendering-bug-different-between-preview-and-actual). In edit mode, the preview shows it correctly as

[image: b dot a rendered correctly with b dot in bold]

Comment: I believe this is wrong. U+200B (`&#8203;` which is the Zero Width Space character btw) isn't part of the [Unicode `Zs` general category](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Zs) [anymore](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#:~:text=U+200B%20ZERO%20WIDTH%20SPACE), and thus isn't supposed to act as a delimiter either. I think there is something going on in commonmark.js with HTML entities in general and I can't get my head of the specs to clearly determine if it's a bug or not, but I suppose it is.

Comment: ... Even `cmark` behaves the same w.r.t. HTML entities.